# QScintilla get the QStringlist from autocompletion

Tags: qt, autocomplete, qscintilla

I am currently using QScintilla to develop my own code editor. 
QScintilla provide autocompletion and calltips feature already. What I want is to get rid of the autocompletion popup widget , retrieve the list it gets, parse and display them with my own widget. 
So here is what I've got:

```
//disable the autocompletion feature:
QsciScintilla::setAutoCompletionSource( QsciScintilla::AcsNone);

//use this function call to get the list from api class:
void updateAutoCompletionList (const QStringList &context, QStringList &list)
```

The problem is ,the updateAutoCompletionList only give me the result from QsciScintilla::AcsAPIs, I have no way to get the result from `QsciScintilla::AcsDocument`.

Is there any way I could get result from `QsciScintilla::AcsDocument`?

thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself.

No available API for me to do so, so I read the source code of QsciScintilla class, which has a method called "startAutoCompletion", you can get the answer from that.

Actually it does search all text, collects the words that match the autocompletion context,avoids duplicates. Not that fancy as I throught, but actually the performance is not as  slow as I throught either :)